# How to update a MySQL table with information from another table without having repeats?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am not very familiar with MySQL, so forgive me if this is a stupid question.
I have 2 tables: `content` and `category`.

`content` has a variety of columns with information, but I am interested in the category column.

`category` basically is just the category column from the first table.

Now, `content` can be anything, even repeats. I want `category` to be one of each and no repeats. So if something new is added to `content` then it adds it to `category` otherwise do nothing.
Right now `content` has many rows while `category` is empty.

What is the best way to go through all of `content` this one time and add one of each to `category`?

And if possible; update `category` as new entries are made to `content` (checking if it already exists and if not add)?

MySQL version: 5.7.28
phpMyAdmin version: 4.9.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways, maybe using only sql, as stated here (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp):

```
INSERT INTO category (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT content.category
FROM content
WHERE condition;
```

Due to the fact that we don't know the structure of the second column I don't know how to help you more than that.
Maybe you can also do something like :

```
SELECT category FROM content
```

map the data to fit into the new table e filter the duplicates e then :

```
INSERT INTO category VALUE(?,?,?,..)
```

Certain works are better if done in the backend instead of taking the logic into the db

The same thing for the *update category as new entries are made to content*:
insert data into category table after you do that into content table, and only if everything is ok put it into category table.

Don't use macro or any plugins, don't automate it in a place where you're not absolute sure you can check things if something happens